# Query Azure AD using Powershell to find which users can access different resources in Azure

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-powershell

**Overview**

I want to have a way to query the Azure AD, and return a list of Azure AD Groups that are assigned to different resources groups in Azure.

**Current Solution**

Currently, i have a powershell script running as a Service principle that authenticates with Azure, then it gets the current subscription. Based on that searches for the logged in user and returns all the security groups the user is assigned to. Which is then checked against all the resources groups the AD group is assigned to, which returns a list of the VM's in the resource groups that the logged in user can access.

This does work, however it takes about 10 minutes to run. We have a 100 resources groups per subscription and its to slow.

I have pasted the code below, and removed any private information.

**Questions**

- Understand a way to make the script run faster - 30 seconds at a max.
- Is there a more efficient way to run the script or a command that is designed for this sole purpose.

I am using Az Powershell 2.4.0 library to create the code.

```
function userLogin($azureAplicationId, $azureAppPassword) 
{
    $azureTenantId= ""
    $azurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $azureAppPassword -AsPlainText -Force
    $psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($azureAplicationId , $azurePassword)
    Connect-AzAccount -Credential $psCred -TenantId $azureTenantId  -ServicePrincipal 
}

function userRGAccessCheck($RG)
{
    $resoruceGroupChoice = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter Resource Group Name "
}

function userRTAccessCheck($RName)
{
    $resoruceNameChoice = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter VM Name "
}


$subAccess = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter Subscription, Press (1) OR (2): `n(1) Microsoft Azure Enterprise Non-Production `n(2) Microsoft Azure Enterprise Production`n"

if ($subAccess -eq 1)
{

    $azureAplicationId =""
    $azureAppPassword = ""
    userLogin -azureAplicationId $azureAplicationId -azureAppPassword $azureAppPassword
    #userRGAccessCheck -RG $reresoruceGroupChoice

} elseif ($subAccess -eq 2)
{

    $azureAplicationId =""
    $azureAppPassword = ""
    userLogin -azureAplicationId $azureAplicationId -azureAppPassword $azureAppPassword
    #userRGAccessCheck -RG $reresoruceGroupChoice
    #userRTAccessCheck -RName $resoruceNameChoice 

} else
{
    Write-Host "Please Enter 1 OR 2"
}


# Arrays for app
$groupArray = @()
$ADAccessGroupArray = @()
$resourceGroupArray = @()


$userObjectID = "USER_OBJECT_ID"

# Get AD User Groups and list of resource groups
$groupArray += (Get-AzADGroup -SearchString 'SS_*' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Id)


foreach($group in $groupArray)
{
    if(Get-AzADGroupMember -GroupObjectId $group | Where-Object {$_.Id -eq $userObjectID})
    {
        $ADAccessGroupArray += $group  
        Write-Host "User has access to group: " $group
    } else
    {
        Write-Host "User does not have access to group: " $group
    }
}


# Get a list of resource groups
$resourceGroupArray += Get-AzResourceGroup | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ResourceGroupName


# Check if the AD group has been assigned to the resource group
foreach ($resourceGroupName in $resourceGroupArray)
{

    foreach ($ADAccessGroup in $ADAccessGroupArray)
    {
      if(Get-AzRoleAssignment -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName | Where-Object {$_.ObjectId -eq $ADAccessGroup})
        {
           Write-Host "User has access to group: " $resourceGroupName

        }
    }
}

$groupArray = $null
$ADAccessGroupArray = $null
$resourceGroupArray = $null
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made some modifications that should help.

```
function userLogin($azureAplicationId, $azureAppPassword) 
{
    $azureTenantId= ""
    $azurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $azureAppPassword -AsPlainText -Force
    $psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($azureAplicationId , $azurePassword)
    Connect-AzAccount -Credential $psCred -TenantId $azureTenantId  -ServicePrincipal 
}

function userRGAccessCheck($RG)
{
    $resoruceGroupChoice = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter Resource Group Name "
}

function userRTAccessCheck($RName)
{
    $resoruceNameChoice = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter VM Name "
}


$subAccess = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter Subscription, Press (1) OR (2): `n(1) Microsoft Azure Enterprise Non-Production `n(2) Microsoft Azure Enterprise Production`n"

if ($subAccess -eq 1)
{

    $azureAplicationId =""
    $azureAppPassword = ""
    userLogin -azureAplicationId $azureAplicationId -azureAppPassword $azureAppPassword
    #userRGAccessCheck -RG $reresoruceGroupChoice

} elseif ($subAccess -eq 2)
{

    $azureAplicationId =""
    $azureAppPassword = ""
    userLogin -azureAplicationId $azureAplicationId -azureAppPassword $azureAppPassword
    #userRGAccessCheck -RG $reresoruceGroupChoice
    #userRTAccessCheck -RName $resoruceNameChoice 

} else
{
    Write-Host "Please Enter 1 OR 2"
}


# Arrays for app
$groupArray = @()
$ADAccessGroupArray = @() -as [System.Collections.Arraylist] # Using Arraylist type
$resourceGroupArray = @()


$userObjectID = "USER_OBJECT_ID"

# Get AD User Groups and list of resource groups
$groupArray = (Get-AzADGroup -SearchString 'SS_*' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Id) # Removed += because it is unnecessary


foreach($group in $groupArray)
{
    if((Get-AzADGroupMember -GroupObjectId $group).where({$_.Id -eq $userObjectID},'First')) # Used where method
    {
        $null = $ADAccessGroupArray.Add($group)  # Add group to arraylist and suppress output. Removed += because it is a slow operation here.
        Write-Host "User has access to group: " $group
    } else
    {
        Write-Host "User does not have access to group: " $group
    }
}


# Get a list of resource groups
$resourceGroupArray = Get-AzResourceGroup | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ResourceGroupName # Removed += because it is unnecessary


# Check if the AD group has been assigned to the resource group
foreach ($resourceGroupName in $resourceGroupArray)
{

      if((Get-AzRoleAssignment -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName).where({$_.ObjectId -in $ADAccessGroupArray},'First')) # used where method
        {
           Write-Host "User has access to group: " $resourceGroupName

        }
}

$groupArray = $null
$ADAccessGroupArray = $null
$resourceGroupArray = $null
```

I added comments to lines that I changed. Here is a summary of the changes:

1. I set `$ADAccessGroupArray` as an arraylist type. This is so that we can access the inherent `Add()` method to update it. If we use an array, which is immutable, you have to create a new array to add more entries. One way to update an array is using `+=`, which is a very inefficient operation as the size of the array grows.

   - Generally, `+=` is not the most efficient approach. Sometimes it is a negligible operation, but I would avoid it unless you know it is negligible.
   - I removed `+=` from your other array assignments because they aren't necessary when you are setting a variable to a command output that returns an array. The result will be an array without `+=`. There are cases where your command returns one value and your variable may not become an array then. There are ways around this using the `,` unary operator or declaring your array ahead of time.
2. I replaced `Where-Object` in favor of the `where()` method. Not only does `where-object` (and `where()`) wait for the LHS operation to complete before it does anything, it will enumerate through all of the pipelined items before it returns a result. Using the `where()` method, we gain access to modes. In both of your cases, I am using the `'First'` mode so that `where()` will stop processing once it finds its first conditional match. This is extremely helpful if you have a list of 1000 objects and the match is within the top half of that list.
3. I removed the nested `foreach` loop within the `$resourceGroupArray` `foreach` loop. This was possible by updating the next `where()` condition to use the `-in` operator. `-in` allows you to find one item within a collection, which is what you were doing for every group. So we reduced the number of `Get-AzRoleAssignment` calls from `ResourceGroups x Groups` to `ResourceGroups`. There should be significant time savings here.